# Tengo un problema al mostrar el nombre del autor de un post

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, relaciones, modelorelacional

Tengo un problema al mostrar el autor de un post creado. Cuando estoy logueado el post se muestra correctamente, ya al desloguearme está generando este error. Adicional a eso mi proyecto en local no me genera este error me funciona normalmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la vista me genera el error al hacer un llamado al nombre del creador del post.

```
<a href="">
        <img style="height: 3rem; width: 3rem; border-radius:100%; object-fit: cover; object- position: center; " src="{{$post->user->profile_photo_url}}" alt="">
        <span>{{__('By')}} {{$post->user->name}}</span>
    </a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el nombre de tu Class User no la encuentra esto puede ser porque quizá deba ser en mayúscula o el nombre el archivo.

Revisa que los nombres coincidan.

Normalmente es

`App\Models\User`